# How to Listen to Rabbit MQ queues with different names in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a chat app that will create a queue for each user that is online and I'm trying to get all the queued messages for this user and the problem is that I only know the name of the queue through the message that comes through and therefore I cant use @RabbitListener to give it a queue name.
Is there any way that I can get all the message queued for a user other than using rabbitTemplate
convert ? since it only gives me one single message other than all of them

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is better to look into a STOMP over WebSocket protocol which is supported as a plugin on RabbitMQ. It indeed creates an individual queue for every user and there is a mechanism to consume all the messages sent to that user.

See WebSocket support in Spring Framework: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#websocket

If you can't do that, you probably should look into a custom solution where you send a queue name to some static exchange for the consumer to be aware of such a new queue which you can add to the `ListenerContainer` at runtime (and remove respectively later). See more info in Spring AMQP: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-queues